# How to reflect changes in the list.selectedItem in the itemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

When I change the:
list.selectedItem.name = 'name2'

then in my item renderer

the dataChange event is not fired!
and I can't update the label with the name property...

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only additions and deletions to a `dataProvider` are updated automatically - for modifications of an existing item to be auto-reflected, the particular property being updated should be declared as `[Bindable]`. Check if `name` property is bindable or not.

```
public class Item
{
  public var noBinds:String = "initvalue";
  [Bindable]
  public var bindMe:String = "initvalue";

  //a constructor that takes two arguments goes here
}

//dp is the dataProvider of a data grid with two columns:

//this will add new item to the grid
dp.addItem(new Item("blah", "blah1"));

/* update the selected item */

//not bindable
dp.selectedItem.noBinds = "new string; but not shown";

//update the Bindable item
dp.selectedItem.bindMe = "new string; this will be updated";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `name` property [bindable](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_4.html#170847).